# Using Url values in JavaScript with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC app. A Razor view in the app is loaded by visiting a route that looks like this:

```
http://localhost:somePort/objects/edit/{id}
```

The `id` is optional. When a user visits this view, I initialize a third-party JQuery plugin. I need to get the ID value from the URL and put it into the initialization. If its null, leave it off. If it exists, add it. Currently, I'm trying the following:

```
$(function () {
  var myPlugin = new Plugin("div#myId", {
    url: "/api/PostData/@Request.Params["id"]",
    init: function () {
      // do stuff
    }
  });
});
```

Unfortunately, the url always shows `/api/PostData/`. Its like it doesn't see the ID value in the URL. How do I put that value here?

Comment: Why don't you just use Javascript Document.URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just put the id into your model from your controller. Then you could do this:

```
$(function () {
  var myPlugin = new Plugin("div#myId", {
    url: "/api/PostData/@Model.Id,
    init: function () {
      // do stuff
    }
  });
});
```